# Including other other slavic languages to grow site?

Tags: discussion

Looking at Area51 and the stats as well as some proposed sites that haven't gotten off the ground, I was thinking it might be useful to expand the scope to include, perhaps, all Eastern Slavic languages or even all Slavic languages.

For example, I am trying to figure out what "Цілую або Цьом", a Ukrainian regionalism from Lviv, means beyond my rough translation of "I kiss or kisses".

It could be a win-win: a larger audience for the site and a more diverse content for pulling in more people. Of course, it could lead to massive flame wars.

Comment: I hope that most people here have noticed by now that there is an [Area 51 proposal for Slavic languages](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102374/slavic-languages).

Answer (score 2):

We cannot expand to that topic since the site is about Russian only, not about Slavic languages, so any topic that is not Russian automatically becomes off topic. Nothing stops you from asking the same question in chat by the way. :D Not sure if users attend it, but you might find someone.

Answer (score 1):

No, it definitely won't a win-win. Imagine a SE site on Germanic languages- all of them - this is too broad. If we include even Ukrainian and Belarusian, not all Slavic languages, in best cases this SE site will be clustered, the users community will be cloven. In more realistic scenario this site will be less and less popular.

Besides, you assumption is wrong actually, stats on Russian SE gradually getting better.

**PS** I'm a strong admirer of all Slavic languages, it is not about any sort of Russian chauvinism or something like that.